# R returns undesired output to screen or drops some return values

Tags: r, function, return, echo, invisible

I have a function to generate some plots:

```
estrat.precios <- function(numeric1,numeric2,factor1,numeric3,numeric4,numeric5,string){
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lattice))

  # histograma de distribución por factor1
  tit=paste("Distribución de descuentos por factor1,",string)
  h2<-histogram(~ numeric2 | factor1,main=tit,xlab = "Descuento")

  # scatterplot de Descuentos vs proyección de venta por grupo
  tit<-paste("Desctos vs. Proyección de Venta por factor1,",string)
  s<-xyplot(numeric2 ~ numeric3 | factor1, main = tit,scales=list(x=list(log=10,equispaced.log=T)),xlab = "Monto Techo",ylab = "Descuento")

  # scatterplot de descuentos vs precio de referencia por grupo
  tit<-paste("Desctos vs precio de referencia por grupo,",string)
  s2<-xyplot(numeric2 ~ numeric4, group= factor1, main = tit, scales=list(x=list(log=10,equispaced.log=T)), auto.key = T, xlab="Precios de Referencia", ylab="Descuento")

  # Density plot de variación respecto de promedio
  tit<-paste("Densidad de variaciones vs promedio de precios,",string)
  d<-plot(density((numeric1-numeric5)/numeric5,na.rm=T),main=tit,cex.main=0.9)

  # boxplot variación respecto de promedio
  bs<-as.character(summary(numeric1-numeric5))
  cs<-paste("Min=",bs[1],"1Q=",bs[2],"Mean=",bs[4],"3Q=",bs[5],"Max=",bs[6])
  tit<-paste("Distribución de variaciones vs promedio,",string)
  b<-boxplot((numeric1-numeric5)/numeric5,main=tit,cex.main=0.9)
  mtext(text=c,side=1)


  return((list(h2,s,s2,d,b)))
}
```

When it's run, it produces a lot of unwanted output to the screen (this is a short excerpt):

```
[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
[[5]]$stats
              [,1]
[1,] -0.2194174757
[2,] -0.0885108962
[3,]  0.0000000000
[4,]  0.0002734618
[5,]  0.1333333333

[[5]]$n
[1] 911
```

I already tried changing the last line of the function to:

```
return(invisible(list(h2,s,s2,d,b)))
```

but then it doesn't generate the first 3 plots: h2, s, s2 (those use Lattice), only d and b.

How can I avoid the unwanted output to the screen and keep the 5 plots?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make this reproducible by supply the values you're trying to input into your function? And can you also describe in greater detail what you're trying to achieve? Do you want the plots or not? What do you want to do with those plots?

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your reply. You can reproduce by invoking the function like `estrat.precios(1:5,seq(0.01,0.05,0.01),c("A","A","B","C","C"),21:25,2:6,1.1:5.1,"string 09")`. I want the plots to analyze a pricing strategy (visually) and then decide if I want to save them or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may display the plots that use Lattice before generating the last two plots and return `invisible`.

```
estrat.precios <- function(numeric1,numeric2,factor1,numeric3,numeric4,numeric5,string)
{
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lattice))
  ...
  s2<-xyplot(numeric2 ~ numeric4, group= factor1, main = tit, scales=list(x=list(log=10,equispaced.log=T)), auto.key = T, xlab="Precios de Referencia", ylab="Descuento")
  # display plots here
  plot(h2)
  plot(s)
  plot(s2)
  # Density plot de variación respecto de promedio
  tit<-paste("Densidad de variaciones vs promedio de precios,",string)
  ...
  invisible(list(h2,s,s2,d,b))
}
```

Comment: When I try your solution, it effectively supresses the output to the screen, but in the place of `s2` a blank canvas is presented (all the other 4 plots are OK). When sourcing the file a warning comes: `display list redraw incomplete`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I see the five plots. Do `Sys.sleep(1)` after each  `plot` statement and after `d<-plot(...)` so that you they are displayed slowly.